# Remove bash permissions for a user

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, bash

I have to create a user that uses /bin/sh as initial shell. This is something I have already done but, I need that this user cannot access bash under any circumstance.
After searching on the internet and asking chatgpt, I am able to modify permissions on the bash script (set to 750). This makes the user cannot execute bash but neither other users.

Is there any other way to do this? I want all the users to keep their permissions except this one.

I am using Ubuntu server 22.04

Comment: For what reason?

Comment: Note that in general allowing your legitimate users to run any program except one is probably the wrong thing to attempt. (A much more common requirement is an allow list with one or just  a few allowed executables)

Comment: You can even remove bash from the system but the user can always download a binary into his home and run `./bash`.

Comment: I advise against uninstalling the default shell on an Ubuntu system. Users with a bash as shell will no longer be able to log in.